# Maximum value of $x$ when equality is given

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$ x + y = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} $$ 
Find maximum value of $x$. $x$ and $y$ are reals.

Comment: "Find maximum value...of $x$"? What does this mean?

Comment: it means most probably to find max value of x satisfying the equation

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. When $\;x,y\in\Bbb N\;$ (since they obviously must be non-negative), what is the maximum value for some $\;x\;$ fulfilling that no matter what $\;y\;$ we take...A little odd question.

Comment: The question makes no much sense, as @DonAntonio suggests.

Comment: Solve as quadric with respect to $\sqrt{x}$ and then maximize the root value + the condition on integers. Would that not work?

Comment: sorry edited just now.

Comment: Well, you now changed **a lot** the question: from integers to reals...anyway, you can find some help, hopefully, in my answer below.

Comment: When restricting to the reals, it is possible for $x$ to be slightly larger than $1$.  As a first step, consider the smaller simpler problem of minimizing $y-\sqrt{y}$.  (*the minimum will be negative and will occur with $y\in (0,1)$*).  Let that minimum be called $m$.  Now, consider finding what $x$ satisfies $x-\sqrt{x}+m=0$.

Answer (score 4):

Try this method of completing the square.

Let $a=\sqrt x$ and $b=\sqrt y$ so that $a^2+b^2=a+b$ and $4a^2-4a+1+4b^2-4b+1=2$ ie $(2a-1)^2+(2b-1)^2=2$

Answer (score 3):

Obviously $x,y\ge0$. We can therefore write $x=r^2\cos^2\theta$ and $y=r^2\sin^2\theta$. Then the equation becomes $$r^2(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=r(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)$$
with $\theta \in [0,\frac\pi2]$ and $r\gt 0$. Dividing by $r$ and multiplying by $\cos\theta$ we get $$\sqrt x=(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)\cos\theta=\cos^2\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta$$
Now find the maximum of the expression on the right. Use formula for the sine and cosine for double angle.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

If you set $f(x)=x-\sqrt{x}$ then you want to solve $f(x)=-f(y)$

The maximum $x$ is reached for the line in green intersecting both curves $f$ and $-f$ at the maximal possible altitude.

So we have to solve $f'(y)=0\iff1-\dfrac1{2\sqrt{y}}=0\iff y=\frac 14$

The corresponding $x$ verifies $f(x)=-f(y)=\dfrac 14$ and this is just a quadratic polynomial to solve to find the $x$ value.

The maximum is then $x=\frac{3+2\sqrt{2}}4\approx 1.4571$

Comment: dont understant what you trying to convey?

Answer (score 3):

Since $x+ y = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$ is symmetric, WLOG, we can consider $x\ge y\ge 0$ or $y=ax, 0\le a\le 1$. Then:
$$x+ ax = \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{ax} \Rightarrow \color{red}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{a}}{1+a} \to \text{max s.t. $0\le a\le 1$}\\
f'(a)=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{a}}{1+a}\right)'=0 \Rightarrow \frac{\frac1{2\sqrt{a}}(1+a)-(1+\sqrt{a})}{(1+a)^2}=0 \Rightarrow \\
a+2\sqrt{a}-1=0 \Rightarrow a=3-2\sqrt{2}\approx 0.17.$$
Note that the function $f(a)$ is continuous at $0\le a\le 1$ and $f(0)=f(1)=1$ and $f(3-2\sqrt{2})=\frac12(1+\sqrt{2})\approx 1.207$. Hence it must be the maximum point (see [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xleeqdy6av)).

So, the maximum value of $x$ is:
$$\color{red}x=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3-2\sqrt{2}}}{1+(3-2\sqrt{2})}\right)^2=\frac14\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^2\approx 1.457.$$

Comment: I don't think that's right. See zwim's answer, or just graph the curve in question to see that the right value should be around $1.46$.

Comment: $1.207^2\approx 1.457$ which is the right answer, so the method is fine. There is an error in the last calculation of $x$.

Comment: @zwim, thank you for pointing to the error. Fixed it.

Comment: +1. Nice method.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$x+y=\sqrt x+\sqrt y\iff \sqrt x\left(\sqrt x-1\right)=\sqrt y\left(1-\sqrt y\right)$$

Now, for any values $\;x,y>1\;$ , the left side above will be positive whereas the right side will be negative (can you see why?), thus we **must** restrict the possible natural values...Can you take it from here?

Comment: sorry the question is edited. it was real.

Comment: can we say then 1?

Comment: The above solves completely the first, original question. Now that it has changed to "real" it at least can help you to realize that $\;y\;$ cannot be greater than $\;1\;$ and $\;x\;$ smaller than one, for example...

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x-\sqrt x$. The question becomes trying to find two real values $x,y$ so that $f(x)=-f(y)$, then maximising one of these values without regard for what happens to the other. After a bit of thinking analysing derivatives, it becomes clear that we want to minimise $f(x)$ so that $f(y)$, and hence $y$, can be maximised. So just set $f'(x)=0$ to find the local minimum value to be $-1/4$, and hence the maximum value of $y$ satisfies $f(y)=1/4$. This is a simple quadratic equation, solve, and you're done!

Answer (score 0):

There are some caveats (we need to assume the existence of a maximum for example) but Lagrange's multipliers method work well here to find the value of the maximum:

Let $f(x,y)=x$ and $g(x,y)=x-\sqrt{x}+y-\sqrt{y}$. We want to find the maximum value of $f$ under constraint $g(x,y)=0$.

We have $\nabla f=\langle 1,0 \rangle$ and $\nabla g = \langle 1-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}},1-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}} \rangle$. At a maximum, we have $\nabla g=\lambda \nabla f$ for some real number $\lambda$. This implies that $1-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}=0$, that is $y=\frac{1}{4}$.

Using the constraint, we have $x-\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{4}=0$ which is equivalent to $a^2-a-\frac{1}{4}$ and $\sqrt{x}=a\geqslant 0$. We obtain $a=\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}$, so $x=\frac{(1+\sqrt{2})^2}{4}=\frac{3+2\sqrt{2}}{4}$.

---

(sloppy) proof of the existence of the global maximum value: The constraint $x+y=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ implies that $x\geqslant 0$ and $y\geqslant 0$. Moreover, if $x$ or $y$ is large enough (x>R or y>R for some $R$ that I am too lazy to determine explicitly :p), $x+y>\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$, so we can assume that $x,y \in [0,R]$.

Now, the function $f(x,y)=x$ is continuous and the set $S=\left\{ (x,y)\in [0,R]^2\; \middle|\;  g(x,y)=0\; \right\}$ is compact (closed and bounded in ${\mathbb R}^2$) so, by the Extreme Value Theorem, $f$ attains its global extreme values on $S$. The global minimum value is obviously obtained at $(0,0)$, while the other one is located by Lagrange's method.